# Greatest lower bound and least upper bound?

Tags: calculus

How would I figure out the glb and lub for the following.

$\{-2,2,-2.1,2.1,-2.11,2.11,...\}$

I would think the lub would be $2.12$

and the glb would be $-2$

And

$\{x:\ln(x)>0\}$

I am not sure how to find the glb and lub of this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you'd actually have in the first case is the least upper bound as $2 +\dfrac 19 = \dfrac {19}{9}$, and greatest lower bound of $-2 - \dfrac 19 = -\dfrac {19}{9}$

In the second case, there is not any upper bound, let alone a least upper bound, as there is no upper bound for x for which $\ln x > 0$. Just keep making $x$ larger and larger. What can you say about the greatest lower bound? We know that "a" lower bound exists at $1$. Is this the greatest lower bound? (Recall that the lub and glb need not actually be *in* the given set.)

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention on my first would keep going like -2,2,-2.1,-2.11,2.11,..... as in it goes on foward

Comment: I see so is the 1/9 the M or how much it increases by.

Comment: 1/9 happens to be equal to $0.11111111\ldots$ It's a repeating decimal, 1's forever.

Comment: Take your calculator and compute, as a decimal, $\dfrac {28}{9}, -\dfrac{28}9$ and see what you get.

Comment: Actually ln(o)=error in my calculator...

Comment: No, @Cameron. Fernando: $\ln 1 = 0$ ($\ln 0$ DNE)  The given set consists of $\{x\mid \ln x >0\}$. So we are interested in the set of $\bf x$ values such that $\ln x > 0$

Comment: Oops. Transposed the $0$ and $1$ to make it true. :-/

Comment: @CameronBuie been there, done that!

Comment: Ok it seem in $x:ln(x)>0$ there is not lub because it keep going into infinity and the glb would be 1 or not?

Comment: Yes Fernando, it would indeed be $1$. No lub. glb = 1.

Comment: I think I am starting to understand a bit better many thanks

Comment: You're welcome, Fernando!

Comment: @amWhy: Nice discourse +1

Answer (score 1):

$2.12$ doesn't work, because (for example) $2.115$ is also an upper bound. In fact, so are $2.1115,$ $2.11115,$ $2.111115,$ and so on. Consequently, if we have a number of the form

$$2.[\text{a bunch of }1\text{s in a row}][\text{digit}]$$

with $\text{digit}>1,$ then it will be an upper bound, but not the *least* upper bound. On the other hand, if we have a number of the form

$$2.[\text{a bunch of }1\text{s in a row}]0[\text{anything else}]\;,$$ then it isn't an upper bound at all. What is the only number that is viable as the least upper bound, then? Note the symmetry of the set about $0$ (that is, $x$ is in the set if and only if $-x$ is). From that, it follows that the glb will be the opposite (or negative) of the lub in this case.

For the second one, I recommend that you rewrite $\{x:\ln(x)>0\}$ as an interval. At that point it should be clear whether or not the set has an lub and/or a glb, and what they are.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to see that any number from your first set is no larger than $2+\frac{1}{9}=2.\dot{1}$ and no smaller than $-2-\frac{1}{9}=-2.\dot{1}$.

For your second set, $\ln(x)>0$ iff $x>1$. So it is actually the set (interval) $(1,\infty)$.

So the infimum is $1$, and the supremum doesn't exist.